# Why <form> </form> break my grid CSS design?

Tags: css, xhtml, css-grid

Please run this short and very elemental code (https://furatena.miami/grid_without_form):

[grid without FORM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSH1B.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://furatena.miami/grid/dtd.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="es"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" /><style type="text/css">@import url("https://furatena.miami/grid/css.css");</style><link rel="icon" href="https://furatena.miami/grid/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /><title>Cloth!!</title></head><body>

<div id="grid_container">


<div id="grid_nkb">
<input id="toggle-menu" class="" type="checkbox" />
<nav class="tc" id="mnutl"><a href="#">Register!</a>
<select name="g" onchange="this.form.submit();"><option value="en" class="pad03">English</option><option value="it" class="pad03">Italiane</option></select>
</nav>
<label for="toggle-menu"><span class="menu-icon"></span></label>
</div>


<div id="grid_info"><p>info</p></div>
<div id="grid_menu"><p>links</p></div>
</div>
<div id="pie">© furatena.miami</div></body></html>
```

you can see this is "saint grial" CSS layout, run "perfect" and is code xHTML 1.1 100% valid on https://validator.w3.org

now **run exactlly THE SAME CODE** but only ADD `<form>` and `</form>` (https://furatena.miami/grid_with_form):

[grid with form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5l1F.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://furatena.miami/grid/dtd.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="es"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" /><style type="text/css">@import url("https://furatena.miami/grid/css.css");</style><link rel="icon" href="https://furatena.miami/grid/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /><title>Cloth!!</title></head><body>

<div id="grid_container">

<form>
<div id="grid_nkb">
<input id="toggle-menu" class="" type="checkbox" />
<nav class="tc" id="mnutl"><a href="#">Register!</a>
<select name="g" onchange="this.form.submit();"><option value="en" class="pad03">English</option><option value="it" class="pad03">Italiane</option></select>
</nav>
<label for="toggle-menu"><span class="menu-icon"></span></label>
</div>
</form>

<div id="grid_info"><p>info</p></div>
<div id="grid_menu"><p>links</p></div>
</div>
<div id="pie">© furatena.miami</div></body></html>
```

continue as code xHTML 1.1 100% valid on https://validator.w3.org
but now the layout is broken

Why `<form> </form>` affect my CSS grid layout?

adding other `<div>` is possible fixed the ERROR but really no't is logic require more tags/divs to fixed the error.

some idea to fixed the error **without add more tags** and no't lost the `toggle-menu`?

Some explicaion please?

Thanks

Comment: ey!, happy 2021, no't is possible fixed **without** add more tags?

Comment: Too bad you didn't include the css.  But in any case, I'm having similar issues with form tags causing a grid blowout.  I would have hoped they would not affect the geometry.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the form tags outside your div#grid_container tags.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://furatena.miami/grid/dtd.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="es"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" /><style type="text/css">@import url("https://furatena.miami/grid/css.css");</style><link rel="icon" href="https://furatena.miami/grid/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /><title>Cloth!!</title></head><body>


<form>
<div id="grid_container">

<div id="grid_nkb">
<input id="toggle-menu" class="" type="checkbox" />
<nav class="tc" id="mnutl"><a href="#">Register!</a>
<select name="g" onchange="this.form.submit();"><option value="en" class="pad03">English</option><option value="it" class="pad03">Italiane</option></select>
</nav>
<label for="toggle-menu"><span class="menu-icon"></span></label>
</div>

<div id="grid_info"><p>info</p></div>
<div id="grid_menu"><p>links</p></div>
</div>
</form>
<div id="pie">© furatena.miami</div></body></html>
```